# Convert an HTML button to ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper, actionlink

I have an html button setup and functioning with a set range of required properties that I'd like to convert to a text-based link instead. Additionally, so I can familiarize myself with working html helpers and intellesense I'd like to see how to shoehorn these properties into an ActionLink:

```
<input type="button" id="RemoveRegistration_Submit<%=row.ID %>" 
value="Remove From Cart" 
onclick="$('#Step2_RemoveRegistrationForm input[name=id]').val('<%=row.ID %>'); $('#Step2_RemoveRegistrationForm').submit();" 
align="right" />
```

thx

Comment: The point of the question is to understand how to transform the above code into an ActionLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be that hard....but I think you mean Html.Link because ActionLink mean you need to generate link from route table.

```
<%= Html.Link("Remove from Cart", "#", new {onclick = "#Step2_RemoveRegistrationForm input[name=id]').val('<%=row.ID %>'); $('#Step2_RemoveRegistrationForm').submit();"}) %>
```

- param#1: linkText
- param#2: href
- param#3: htmlAttributes

  public static string Link(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string href, object htmlAttributes)
  {

  TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a"){ InnerHtml = linkText; }

  tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);

  tagBuilder.MergeAttributes("href", href);

  return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

  }

and don't forget to <%@ Import Namespace="xxxxxx" %> on the view in order to use the extension method.

Comment: Any chance I could get you to expand on the 'Link' vs 'ActionLink' usage? Html.Link is tossing an error: '...does not contain a definition for 'Link' and no extension method 'Link' ...

Intellesense doesn't list 'Link'. I'm working against the release version of MVC - is this part of Futures?

Comment: It is a simple extension method. I will put on my post.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons can't act like links without javascript.
In general - that's a bad practice (search engines can't index your page correctly etc.).

I would recommend you to use anchor tags and make them look like a buttons.

But if you truly need it - [this](http://www.acceptedeclectic.com/2008/12/aspnet-mvc-attempts-to-extend.html) article provides an answer.

**EDIT:**

Sorry. Shot my answer little bit too fast.

This isn't exactly what you are asking (HtmlHelper is not involved) but that's how I would solve this problem:

in view i would define anchor (anchors without hrefs do pass W3 validation):

```
<a id='removefromcart_<%=row.ID%>' title='Remove from cart' 
   class='remove-link' />
```

in external javascript file:

```
   var onclick = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(event.targetSource());

        //tag ids should be injected through view asp/cx
        $('#Step2_RemoveRegistrationForm input[name=id]') 
            .val(link.attr('id').split('_')[1])
    };
    $('a[id^=removefromcart]').click(onclick);
```

in css:

```
 a {cursor:pointer;} /*anchors without href by default haven't pointer*/
```

I believe it would be too messy to poke around with javascript in HtmlHelpers.

**EDIT2:**

Anchor text is defined inside tags. I always confuse that. And it seems that targetSource() [is wrong](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event) too. Try to rewrite it: event.targetSource()=>event.target.

Comment: I'm looking for the inverse...I want a button to look like a link.

Comment: I've tried the code as is but without some text between <a ...> & a closing </a> i don't see how anything becomes visible/clickable. I've added:

<a id='removefromcart_<%=row.ID%>' title='Remove from cart' class='remove-link'>remove from cart</a>

Now a link is visible but nothing fires onclick.

thx

Comment: Sorry - you are right. To add text - add it between opening&closing tags. Nothing happens because you didn't add javascript, didn't call it when document is ready or there is an error in it (i didn't check it, just wrote how i remembered it).